# For every sufficiently large $m$ there exists $k$ such that $m = k + \tau(k)$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility, divisor-counting-function

Let $\tau(k)$ , be the number of positive divisors of natural number $k$. Is it true, that there exists $n_0$ , such that for every $m\geq n_0$ there exists $k  \in\mathbb{N}$ such that:
$$
m = k + \tau(k)
$$

I have tried to use the following formula for $\tau$:
$$
\tau(p_1^{k_1}\ldots p_{s}^{k_s}) = (k_1 +1)\cdot\ldots \cdot(k_s +1),
$$
Where $p_1, \ldots, p_s$ are different prime numbers.

Intuitively, I think that the answer will be no. So, we can assume the contrary (that such $n_0$ exists) and try some infinite series of numbers (primes, factorials, primorials, etc.), which can't be written in the form $k + \tau(k)$ for every $k$. But my attempts weren't successful.

So, I will be grateful for hints and ideas.

Comment: Have you tried a brute Force attack? Compute $k+\tau(k)$ for the first million or so k-s and see if any values are skipped.

Comment: yes, I have tried brute force attack and found no regularities)

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_partition

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)  helps as well.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2JM2oImb9Qg&app=desktop

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee, thank you, but I really don't guess. how to use your hints

Comment: @MikhailGoltvanitsa FYI, note the currently unanswered question [contest problem related to divisor function](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3660919/602049) is asking to prove there's an infinite number of values for which there's no solution to $k + \tau(k)$ (although the other question uses the symbol $\sigma$ instead). As such, your intuition appears to be correct, i.e., there is no such minimal value of $n_0$.

Comment: You can get a vertically centred ellipsis for use between binary operators like $\cdot$ using `\cdots`.

Comment: @JohnOmielan: That question has been edited in the meantime (by the author). It now asks to prove that there are only finitely many numbers that cannot be written like this.

Answer (score 2):

[contest problem related to divisor function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3660919/contest-problem-related-to-divisor-function) 
Look at Loppukilpailija's answer. I think he solved your problem negatively.

Answer (score -1):

We are looking at, a specific composition. Included, is a multiplicative partition( number of divisors, in this case). [Highly composite numbers](https://oeis.org/A002182) are likely to have the highest number of multiplicative partitions due to highest divisor number up to a point. These may not be so dense on the naturals however. 12 divisors comes about in one of 4 ways:$$p^{11}\\p^5q\\p^3q^2\\p^2qr$$

Comment: I have understood this observation before. But I don't know how to use it...

Comment: show that most numbers m can be written as a highly composite number plus a natural number with a highly composite number of divisors.