# contest problem related to divisor function

Tags: number-theory, contest-math

Prove or disprove that there is only a finite set  of numbers which cannot be written as n + $\sigma(n)$, where sigma(n) - number of divisors of n.
I know that $\sigma (p_1^{\alpha_1}\cdot...\cdot p_n^{\alpha_n}) = \prod(1+\alpha_i)$

i've tried to construct an infinite sequence and thought about numbers like $((2^2)^2)...^2$ but it all didn't worked out.

i will appreciate any kind of hints.

Comment: FYI, the starting list of integers which cannot be written in the form of $n + \sigma(n)$ (although it uses the alternate expression of $\tau$, just like the related SE question [For every sufficiently large $m$ there exists $k$ such that $m = k + \tau(k)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3249563/602049)), is at [OEIS A036434](http://oeis.org/A036434). The linked page at [Refactorable Numbers - A Machine Invention](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/colton/joisol.html) says ...

Comment: (cont.) "The HR (or Hardy-Ramanujan) program invents and analyses definitions in areas of pure mathematics, including finite algebras, graph theory and number theory." Later, in section [$4.2$ New Sequences Invented by HR](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/colton/joisol.html#newseqs), it says the following were invented & considered enough interest to add to the OEIS, with A$036434$ being item #$4$. As I could not find any other details, either at the OEIS entry or elsewhere, about there being an infinite # of values, if you get a proof, you may wish to add it to the OEIS entry.

Comment: What is the source of the problem?

Comment: the source is yandex data school entrance exam (moscow)

Comment: @JohnOmielan seems like there might be infinitely many numbers like this: http://oeis.org/A036431

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There exists infinitely many positive integers which cannot be expressed as $n + d(n)$, where $d(n)$ is the number of divisors of $n$.

Let $C$ be a large constant. By the Chinese remainder theorem one can construct a positive integer $K$ such that $d(K+1), d(K+2), \ldots , d(K+C)$ are all larger than $C$. Consider now the number of integers $m \in [1, K+C]$ which can be expressed as $m = n + d(n)$. Clearly for any such $m$ we must have $n \le K+C$. By construction, any such $n$ must in fact satisfy $n \le K$. Thus, there is at most $K$ such $m$ in $[1, K+C]$ with the desired representation.

Comment: Could you please formulate your version of Chinese remainder theorem, it's not clear for me how you use it in your argument :( Thank you !

Comment: seems like i got it!

Comment: what i actually got:
system
\begin{cases}
x \equiv -1 mod(p_1,...,p_{i_1}) \\
...\\
x \equiv -C mod (p_{i_{c-1}},..., p_{i_c})
\end{cases}
has a solution where all $p_j$ distinct prime numbers and $1 = i_0 < i_1 <...< i_c$ with $i_{k+1} - i_k$ sufficiently large to make $x + k +1 $ have enough divisors.

Comment: Indeed, that is the idea. (One can also work with prime powers: take congruences of the form $x \equiv -i \pmod{p_i^C}$, where $p_1, \ldots , p_C$ are distinct primes.)